# What is the main relationship between the inflection points and the roots?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, roots, cubics

How does inflection point equal the average of real parts of three roots in a cubic equation and what does it refer to in nth-degree polynomial equations?

Comment: $n^{th}$ degree polynomials have largest exponent $n$. Cubics are $3^{rd}$ degree polynomials, e.g. Rigorous definitions talk about the power of the largest term with non-zero coefficient, to prevent confusion.

Comment: @DavidDiaz I cannot really relate it to this, can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show algebraically that the inflection point, $a$, of a cubic equation with three real roots is the average of the roots.

---

Assume a cubic has three real roots, $r_1, r_2$, and $r_3$. Then it is expressible in the following form:

$$c\cdot(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$$
$$= c\cdot\left(x^3 - (r_1+r_2+r_3)x^2 + (r_1 r_2+r_1 r_3+r_2 r_3)x - r_1 r_2 r_3\right)$$

The inflection point, $a$,  is the point at which the second derivative equals zero.

$$f''(a) = 0$$

Note that the second derivative of this cubic is a line.

$$f''(x) = c\left(6x - 2(r_1 + r_2 + r_3)\right)$$

Setting this equal to zero and solving, we have

\begin{align}
c\left(6a - 2(r_1 + r_2 + r_3)\right)&= 0\\
6a - 2(r_1 + r_2 + r_3) &= 0 \tag{constant $c$ is non-zero}\\
6a &= 2(r_1 + r_2 + r_3)\\
a &= \frac{r_1 + r_2 + r_3}{3}
\end{align}

$$\square$$